# Gzip compression over SSL with Safari?

Tags: ssl, safari, gzip, content-length

I ran into a really weird issue this morning when trying to access a web app I'm building using an iPad (Safari Mobile/Webkit). On the front end, the web app relies heavily on XHR/Ajax requests. On the back end, the server is configured to gzip compress responses if the "Accept-Encoding" includes "gzip".

Everything was working great until I flipped the server to SSL. Then I started getting intermittent "CFURLErrorDomain:303" errors in Safari.

After a quick search I found this link:

http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/45/posts/12034/failed-to-load-resource-safari-issue.aspx

According to the link, Safari requires a content-length header when making XHR (ajax) request over SSL/HTTPS. In my case, the server is gzipping content directly to the output stream so I have no way of knowing what the final content length will be.

As a workaround, I added the following logic on the server:

```
    if (request.isEncrypted()) gzip =
        !request.getHeader("User-Agent").toLowerCase().contains("webkit");
```

In other words, if the connection is encrypted via SSL, and the browser is some webkit derivative (e.g. Safari, Chrome, etc), then don't compress the output. This seems to work but it really slows things down.

So my question is this:

Does Safari support gzip compressed responses over SSL or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the error I was seeing was a bug in the server and nothing to do with Safari. The server was relying on chunked transfer encoding when compressing large byte arrays. Individual "chunks" were broken up into pieces (header, body, trailer) and sent to the client in separate messages. The SSL client (safari) was expecting one contiguous "chunk" so it didn't know what to do when it saw an incomplete chunk. The server has been patched and the issue is now resolved.

Comment: I'm having the same issue I think.  How exactly did you patch your server to fix this?  I think I need to do something similar and it looks like you're using Java as well.

Comment: Even in July 2020 gzip compressed pages cannot be displayed in Safari (Desktop) on Mac, if delivered over HTTPS. How exactly did you patch your server to fix this?